# :first-child with different class names

Tags: css, less, css-selectors

I have a HTML structure:

```
<div class="home-view">
     <div class="view-header">Header</div>
     <div class="view-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

And I would like to style the first item of `home-view`. In this case, it's `view-header`, but sometimes there is no header and the `view-content` will be the first item in `home-view`.

The first item in `home-view` should get some styles.

I've been trying with `.home-view:first-child`, but no luck there since it's children have different class-names (I think). Any advice?

Comment: Will this [suit](http://jsfiddle.net/7cNZS/1/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.home-view > *:first-child { background-color:red; }
```

...will select the first sub element of any type that is a first child.

Comment: Thanks, but same remark as Kevin. The included divs all contain some more divs and every first div is marked red...

Answer (score 2):

Since both elements are `div`s you could specify the first `div` within .home-view

```
.home-view div:first-child{
    background: red;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7cNZS/

Comment: A step in the right direction, but both divs contain some nested divs and every first div inside the div is marked red...

Answer (score 1):

```
.home-view > div:first-of-type{ background-color:red; }
```

The :first-of-type selector matches every element that is the first child, of a particular type, of its parent.

[More....](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You responded to the previous answers that you only wanted the direct child elements to be styled, and not child elements below them.

So I'll adapt those answers and give you an answer that meets that requirement:

```
.home-view>div:first-child{
    background: red;
}
```

The difference here is the `>` selector between `.home-view` and `div` instead of a space. This forces it to only select immediate children of `.home-view`, and not divs that are further down the tree, whereas a space between them would tell it to select any matching child elements down the tree.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
$('.home-view').children().eq(0);
```

Comment: There's no _JQuery_ tag.

Comment: Ohh.. missed that, my bad!